# How to Execute Base Class's Method Before Implementors's Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have the following page

```
public partial class GenericOfflineCommentary : OfflineFactsheetBase
{
}
```

where `OfflineFactsheetBase` is defined as

```
public class OfflineFactsheetBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public OfflineFactsheetBase()
    {
        this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
        this.PreInit += new EventHandler(this.Page_PreInit);
    }

    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["data"] != null)
        {
            this.PageData = StringCompressor.DecompressString(Request.QueryString["data"]);
            this.ExtractPageData();
        }
    }
}
```

`OfflineFactsheetBase` has the following `virtual` method:

```
public virtual void ExtractPageData()
{
    // get stuff relevant to all pages that impmement OfflineFactsheetBase 
}
```

which is implemented in all pages that impmement OfflineFactsheetBase as follows:

```
public partial class GenericOfflineCommentary : OfflineFactsheetBase
{
    public override void ExtractPageData()
    {
            // get stuff relevant to an OfflineCommentary page.
    }
}
```

Currently, only `GenericOfflineCommentary`'s ExtractPageData() is firing. How can I modify this to first run `OfflineFactsheetBase`'s ExtractPageData() and then `GenericOfflineCommentary`'s?

**edit:** I'm trying to avoid having to call `base.ExtractPageData()` in every implementor. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `ExtractPageData` method non-virtual, and call a `ExtractPageDataInternal` virtual method :

```
public void ExtractPageData()
{
    // get stuff relevant to all pages that impmement OfflineFactsheetBase

    // base implementation
    ...

    // call derived class implementation
    this.ExtractPageDataInternal();
}

protected virtual void ExtractPageDataInternal()
{
    // implementation to be defined by derived class
}
```

The derived class will only override `ExtractPageDataInternal`, not `ExtractPageData`, so the base implementation will always be executed

Answer (score 0):

Revised after clarification

```
 public class OfflineFactsheetBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public OfflineFactsheetBase ( )
    {
        this.Load += new EventHandler ( this.Page_Load );
        this.PreInit += new EventHandler ( this.Page_PreInit );
    }

    protected void Page_PreInit ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if ( Request.QueryString [ "data" ] != null )
        {
            this.PageData = StringCompressor.DecompressString ( Request.QueryString [ "data" ] );
            this.ExtractPageData ( );
        }
    }

    public void ExtractPageData ( )
    {
        // get stuff relevant to all pages that implement OfflineFactsheetBase 
        // ....blah...
        InternalExtractPageData ( );
    }
    // Could be abstract if the class where
    protected virtual void InternalExtractPageData ( )
    {
        // get stuff relevant to all pages that impmement OfflineFactsheetBase 
    }
}

public partial class GenericOfflineCommentary : OfflineFactsheetBase
{
    public override void ExtractPageData ( )
    {
        // get stuff relevant to an OfflineCommentary page.
    }
}
```

Is OfflineFactsheetBase abstract? If so, make ExtractPageData protected abstract and call it from a public method on the base, see [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141104/how-to-enforce-a-method-call-in-the-base-class-when-overriding-method-is-invoke)

Comment: but that means that I have to include that line in every implementor's ExtractPageData(), doesn't it? Question Edited to reflect this.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, don't know how to add hyperlinks in a comment so edited above to point to an example of the Template pattern