# How to apply Common Codes in Inherited BaseEdit for Inheriting Classes; in order to build a read only user

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

A n-tier layer project.

In businesslayer, there is a inherited Class Called **BaseEdit** which contains contractor and base properties.

There are about 30 **CustomEdit** (inheriting classes), all of them has methods "**Load**","**Save**" and "**Delete**".

The require for this existing system is to add a **readonly** user.

Possible solutions considering the cost of works:

1) Modify the **BaseEdit** so all **CustomEdit** can stay the same.
The system will check 'user role' in session by using httpcontext then to accept or reject the user's action.

So Question1: Can vb.net achieve this?

'BaseEdit

```
Public Function Save() Boolean
 'check session in BusinessLayer, if it is ready only user
 'then Validation is false
End Function
```

'CustomEdit

```
Public Function Save() Boolean
 'Proceed the save
End Function
```

But when I invoke CustomEdit.Save(), the BaseEdit.Save() will not be invoked.
Seems vb.net doesn't support this kind of partial methods.
Is there a way to achieve this without changing CustomEdit?

2) In SQL Server, Check Session States and restrict user access to Insert or Update StoredProc.
Question 2: Should it be taken place in SQL Server? Anyone has experiences about this? Any comments for advantage/disadvantage?

Question 3:In my opinion, the user restriction should be achieve in web layer or the Business layer by authentic controls.
Someone told me the security access stuff should be as close as to the database, is it right?

Comment: Don't add C# tag just for attracting more attention. You are explicitely asking for VB.NET.

Comment: So you've overridden `Save` but want the base classes `Save` to be called. Then either don't override it or call `base.Save()`.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I modified the question a bit. The save() in BaseEdit is still not called, if I call Custom.Save() and without saying BaseEdit.Save() in Custom.Save().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141104/how-to-enforce-a-method-call-in-the-base-class-when-overriding-method-is-invok/1141110#1141110), and I believe the answer would be valid for you too. Modify BaseEdit to be the only class with Save(), in which you call the abstract "ProtectedSave()", which all base classes must implement. That way you control what and which methods are executed in the Save() function.

Comment: Oops, thought this had C# in the tags...not sure about VB, if it does inheritance then this should be valid

Comment: Thx, I see ur mean. Called BaseEdit.Save() and process the "InternalSave()". It's good but the drawback is need to change the name of "Save()" in every CustomEdit.

Comment: Or I'm trying to add this check in constructor.

Comment: Then you will have to change all implementations of Save() in the CustomEdit class to call base.Save(). Can't think how to do it without changing code.

Comment: Resharper has a nice feature for this where you change the name on the base class and it will reflect across your solution...maybe worth a try